# Using bash how can I test for output?

Tags: bash, shell, aix

In UNIX (IBM AIX) I want to write a bash script to grep the output of a command and test the results.

Here is the example...

```
/usr/local/bin/myprog --test

Device Mfg:              IBM
Product ID:              MYPRODUCT123
Product Revision:        384
```

Using bash, how can I grep the output so that I can...

1. Grab the Product ID output (MYPRODUCT123) in a variable without spaces.
2. Test to make sure Product Revision = 384 and not blank or a different value.

I tried to pipe the output to "grep -q" in a if statement but my results are sub optimal, I need to grep for the exact number of spaces for it to work and that may not be consistent across; so ideally strip all spaces when testing the output.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: you need to show more of your attempts or expect being downvoted

Comment: The whole point of `grep -q` is to *not* produce any output. Remove `-q` from your attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

- `Product ID` always comes before `Product Revision`
- `Product ID` and `Product Revision` only show up once in the output
- don't want to have to worry about case sensitivity
- `awk` is an acceptable replacement (for `grep`) [ie, this is a bit easier with `awk`]

Proposed `bash` solution:

```
$ read prod_id prod_rev <<< $(/usr/local/bin/myprog --test | awk  -F: 'tolower($0) ~ /product id|product revision/ {print $2}')

$ echo "prod_id : ${prod_id}"
prod_id : MYPRODUCT123

$ echo "prod_rev : ${prod_rev}"
prod_rev : 384
```

Explanation:

- pipe output to `awk`
- `awk` configured with colon (`:`) as input field separator (F)
- `tolower($0)` converts each input line to all lower case (for case-insenstive testing only)
- `~ /product id|product revision/` => apply our dual lower case patterns against the lower case input
- if the line matches one of our patterns then `print $2` => print what comes after the (first) input field separator (`:`); this should print the value with its original spelling/capitalization intact (ie, without the application of the `tolower()`)
- at this point our output is a string of two values that we'll feed back to our variables via a here-string (`<<<`) construct
- store values in the `prod_id` and `prod_rev` (bash) variables for later use

---

Edit:

Attempt to address comment about `awk` generating 2 lines of output (as expected), but bash not storing a value in the `prod_rev` variable:

```
read prod_id prod_rev <<< $(/usr/local/bin/myprog --test | awk  -F: 'BEGIN {ORS=" "} tolower($0) ~ /product id|product revision/ {print $2}')
```

Same explanation as the initial solution, with the addition of `BEGIN/ORS=" "` to force the output to be placed on a single line (ORS == output record separator => change from default newline to a space).

Comment: This worked great and a great explanation on the process for my learnings.

Comment: After a bit more testing, this only seems to output prod_id, nothing there for prod_rev variable. All of your assumptions are also correct.

Comment: Could be either a) odd behavior with the `bash` version you're working with or b) potential typo (did you cut-n-paste *exactly* what I've provided?  or did you type it by hand and if so have you verified spelling of the `prod_rev` variable?); What do you get for output if run just the commands from inside the `$(...)` construct, ie, myprog/awk?

Comment: The output I get is MYPRODUCT123 and 384, each on its own line but with different number of spaces at the start of the new line. Using bash 4.4.12 (IBM AIX).

Comment: OK, the output is as expected; I don't have access to an AIX host at the moment; I'm wondering if your `bash` implementation is having problems reading the value from the 2nd line ... I've updated my answer with an additional suggestion that adds the `ORS` option to the `awk` call ... this forces all of the output to appear on a single line; see if that makes a difference ...

Comment: That worked better, is there a way to tweak it so that the stored variable can support values with space? If "Product ID" returns MYPRODUCT 123 (note the space between MYPRODUCT and 123)? With the example you got, this does not seem to work. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: This back-n-forth is getting a bit drawn out; I recommend you post a new question with a complete set of potential inputs and the desired outputs; see [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps.

```
value=$(/usr/local/bin/myprog --test | awk -F':| +' '/Product ID:/{val=$NF;next} /Product Revision:/ && NF==4{print val}' Input_file)
```

**Explanation:** Making a variable named value whose value is stored using `$`(command), now first running your command `myprog` and by using `|`(pipe) outputting its output to `awk` command as a standard Input for it.

In `awk` command making field separator by doing `-F':| +'` as : or space. Then searching for string Product ID: in a line and saving its last field(`$NF`)'s value to a variable named val, using next will skip all the `next` statements. Now mentioning another condition where checking if a line has Product Revision: in it and it's number of fields are 4(to make sure it is Product Revision value is NOT NULL), if this condition is TRUE then printing value of variable val.

When you do `echo $value`, it should show you value of it without any space. I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F":" '/^Product ID/{id=$2}/^Product Revision/ && $2 == 384{ print id,$2}'  filename
```